# Object identity and protocols

Tags: swift, swift-protocols

Is it not possible in Swift to compare object identity against a protocol type? I'm trying to find a built-in way to do this. This is my example:

```
protocol MyProtocol {
  var propertyFoo: Int { get set }
}

class MyProtocolImpl: MyProtocol {
  var propertyFoo = 100

  func test(arg: MyProtocol) {
    if arg === self {               // error
      print("Same object")
    } else {
      print("Different object")
    }
  }
}
```

---

I get the following error:

Binary operator '===' cannot be applied to operands of type 'MyProtocol' and 'MyProtocolImpl'

Comment: Looks like it has to be downcast with: 

`if arg is MyProtocolImpl && arg as! MyProtocolImpl === self`

Comment: Yes, you are right ))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To compare object identity, the operands must be reference types.

So you should declare MyProtocol as `class` protocol. Try:

```
protocol MyProtocol: class {
//                 ^^^^^^^
    var propertyFoo: Int { get set }
}
```

OR If `MyProtocol` can be also implemented by `struct` or `enum`, compare with conditional downcasted object.

```
if arg as? MyProtocolImpl === self {
//    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

This works because `===` accepts `Optional` parameters.

```
func ===(lhs: AnyObject?, rhs: AnyObject?) -> Bool
```

Comment: Still learning Swift. Class-only protocols was a missing link. Thanks!